# Display array value one by one

Tags: php

Hii I have a two arrays one contains name and another contains id. Now I want to display the array value one by one like Id1 then name1 Id2 then Name2. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Write a simple loop. Echo out values in loop. Surely you can research how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use a `for` loop?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < min(count($ar1), count($ar2)); $i++)
{
    echo $ar1[$i] . ' ' . $ar2[$i];
}
```

Using a `foreach` loop as suggested by Y U NO WORK is possible too, if the arrays have the same length.

Comment: Well, if he has `id` and `name`, its pretty sure that the arrays have the same lenght^^.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($array1 as $k => $v) {
    echo $v . " || " . $array2[$key];
}
```